# Looping in textarea java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I need help why can not repeat textarea when I display the data from database.

I've tried a variety of ways, but have not found how to perform all the data is in the database.

This is the last code I tried so far

```
void tampilkata(){

    try {
        String sql = "select kosakata.*, jabar1.*, jabar2.*, jabar3.* from kosakata "
                                            + "inner join jabar1 on kosakata.kode=jabar1.kode "
                                            + "inner join jabar2 on kosakata.kode=jabar2.kode "
                                            + "inner join jabar3 on kosakata.kode=jabar3.kode "
                                            + "where kosakata.kosakata like'%"+Textfield1.getText()+"%'";
        PreparedStatement ps = koneksi.getKoneksi().prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

        while(rs.next()){
            jTextarea1.setText("Kata utama :\t\t"+rs.getString("kosakata")+" \n\t"+rs.getString("arti")
                                            +"\n\t\t\t"+rs.getString("jabar1")+"\n\t"+rs.getString("arti1")
                                            +"\n\t\t\t"+rs.getString("jabar2")+"\n\t"+rs.getString("arti2")
                                            +"\n\t\t\t"+rs.getString("jabar3")+"\n\t"+rs.getString("arti3"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(panel_terjemahan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I am very grateful for your help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `jTextarea1.append(...`

Comment: Zouzou and john,, thanks,,,
its work

Comment: And move your database queries to a background thread to avoid blocking the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method : `jTextarea1.append(yourString)`

> Appends the given text to the end of the document. Does nothing if the
>   model is null or the string is null or empty.